# WebView in Alert Dialog Box

Tags: android, webview, gif

I am using `WebView` view in my app to render a `gif` file in an Alert Dialog box , it says Web page not found, but i am certain that the file was in the asset folder

Main activity:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EasyGame.this);
                    WebView v = new WebView(EasyGame.this);
                    v.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    builder.setView(v);
                    builder.create().show();
                    v.loadUrl("file:///assets/animations/cloud.gif");
```

gifwebview.java:

```
public class GIFWebView extends WebView {

    public GIFWebView(Context context, String path) {
        super(context);
        loadUrl(path);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: can you share code or log cat?

Comment: try to load a html file which load the gif inside an img tag instead

Comment: @eriuzo it is not an image sir its a gif animation could it be possible? Sorry for my mistakes im just new here. thank you

Comment: What's `GIFWebView`? I don't see it used in the alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
v.loadUrl("file:///assets/animations/cloud.gif");
```

to

```
v.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/animations/cloud.gif");
```

This might solve your problem.